# Java (Java EE 6) Get logged in user from linux-system

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

My first option was the UnixSystem-class and the SolarisSystem-class. But it appears that these classes are missing in the Java EE-version and I've checked both Java EE 6 and Java EE 7. Can anybody explain why they are missing and what's my alternatives now?

System.getProperty("user.name") is of course not an option.

Comment: you need to be looking at sso solutions

Comment: You are so right. I've totally misunderstood my own environment-setup I'm afraid. I guess this question can be removed. Thanks for the smack in the head sir hehe! :)